# Ionic Git and/or GitHub Git?

Tags: git, github, ionic-framework

I recently started working with Ionic for a project that a friend and I are working on from the ground up. I have been searching around for the best Mobile App development since I see there's Ionic, React Native, Cordova (which is required for all), and PhoneGap. We worked with PhoneGap but we think Ionic may be easier to implement. We also were looking at Firebase for Web hosting and data (although I previously was looking at Heroku and then Mongo Atlas).

Anyways, I got really confused as soon as I created a test project to start tinkering with it to understand it, but was greeted with... Git...

I already have a repository for this in Git and I am assuming that Ionic has this built in to make it easier and more organized when you develop, but now I'm in a pickle. We want a web interface, which we were going to run in an express style, but, at least the way I see it, Firebase doesn't exactly support a "middleware style" web app. I was going to process requests from the web and mobile applications through this server since there won't be much information to pass through, and making a secure link between a web server and a data processing server would be more trouble than it's worth.

Back to Git. Should I just push to Ionic for testing and then when I'm satisfied, push to GitHub? Also, would it be a good idea to make separate repositories (e.g: Application-Mobile, Application-Web, Application-Server)?

I apologize for having a broad question here and that I'm, what I think, am a "Introductory" level developer. I have worked with React two years ago (but it has changed a LOT), as well as express, a little mongoose, Mongo, just started learning SQL, JQuery, dabbled in PHP, dabbled in Perl and have just barely worked with PhoneGap and Ionic.

I know the type of application we want will require this diversity, but I want to understand a little bit of what I'm getting into before I'm head deep and can't back out. I did a bit of research, but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

What would you guys do?

Comment: "...Ionic has this built in..." Has what built in? Can you explain more what you are seeing for those of us who are familiar with Git but not with Ionic?

Comment: Basically, when I created the Ionic application and `cd`ed into it, it changed to a `master` branch. I went on Ionic's website and logged into my console. Sure enough when I go under the app, it has this thing where it uses Git. 

The best way I can explain it is that it has it's own build in "GitHub" which is completely separate from GitHub itself.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, seperating backend, web and mobile is better way  if u use backend for web and mobile.

Developers use Github, GitLab to exchange code and control the versions.

You can start with tutorials.